# Remove 'relevance' tab when viewing user activity on a particular tag

Tags: feature-request, search

I think having `relevance` there is totally irrelevant. ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=active&q=user:1122645%20%5Bqt%5D))

Am curious how it's determined too.

Comment: It's shown on all search results; there are tons of examples where it doesn't really make sense (basically anything that doesn't include an actual search string)

Answer (score 1):

I'd disagree with removing it

It's used in other searches, and ideally the search result interface should stay uniform regardless of what your search keywords are

Making an except for specific search terms can just lead to a maintenance nightmare later on down the road.

I am also curious about how items in that tab are determined though. I was testing with [searching](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:302677%20%5Basync%5D) the "async" tag on my own profile since I know there are few questions tagged with it, but I can't find a pattern :)

Comment: It's not exactly *a specific search term*, as much as a [tag:qt] is not a search term.

Comment: @Tshepang True, but tags are often used in conjunction with regular search keywords, so making a special case to hide an unobtrusive piece of the interface when doing tag-only searches seems like more trouble than its worth :)